# src\components\Home.js Line 6:10: 'Container' is not defined react/jsx-no-undef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-2016

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from "styled-components";

function Home() {
    return (
        <Container>
            home
        </Container>
    )
}

export default Home
```

the error comes

```
src\components\Home.js Line 6:10: 'Container' is not defined react/jsx-no-undef
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: The error is correct. `Container` isn't defined.

Comment: how to slove it

Comment: Have you created a `Container` component? If you have import it into `Home`.

Comment: plz tell me what that command to import Container

Comment: I can't. I don't know if you've created one, and I don't know what your folder structure looks like if you have. Maybe [start with this](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define Container first for example:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from "styled-components";

const Container = styled.Text`
 font-size: 42;
`;

function Home() {
    return (
        <Container>
            home
        </Container>
    )
}

export default Home
```

If you have a `Container` that you are already created and exported defaultl then import it as follows

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from "styled-components";
import Container from "file-path";

function Home() {
    return (
        <Container>
            home
        </Container>
    )
}

export default Home
```

If you export Container as constant then you need to import as

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Container } from "file-path";

function Home() {
    return (
        <Container>
            home
        </Container>
    )
}

export default Home
```

[For more please refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52304419/13913053)